# How to remove highlight of the views in preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, intellij-idea

After the 3.3 update, I've noticed that most of the views in my XML file has this weird highlight in the preview screen on the right and it very annoying and preventing me of know what my views really look like.

any idea how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: This happens when LinearLayout is present in your XML. Just try replacing your LinearLayout with RelativeLayout or other layout and you can see that the grey border vanishes

Comment: You're right, that's weird ..! But I like my LinearLayout and I don't want to replace it.! any idea how to remove it while using LinearLayout .!

Answer (score 0):

I guess just tap on the gray background and this removes all selections highlights.

Comment: What view is this ?

Comment: that's main root layout

Comment: I mean what you use as wrapper for the text views?

Comment: I don't really get what you mean?